# How can I get a temporary fix for a broken 'g' key on keyboard?

Tags: transforms, shortcut, hardware, keymap

I have a hardware issue where it appears that the <kbd>G</kbd> key is broken. I won't be able to get into town to buy another keyboard for at least 2 days, but I can't figure out how to remap it properly. Nothing I change has the same effect as it did.

Comment: Hello, you can either remap it in the Preferences, or select the Move tool in the tool panel?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the N key in object mode to get a translation bar and manually slide the translation sliders.  You can also rebind the 3D move command which is on G under

```
edit --> Preferences --> Keymap
```

There is a search bar.  Set the search mode from name to key-binding and search "G".  In this case I think you want to rebind "Move" under 3D

Bind it to another letter, but first you need to remove the key you want to set the move command to from the other key binding it occupies.

Remember what you changed, maybe write it down as a text file on your desktop so you can reset it.